# Can Lower bound of Upper bound of f(n) equal Upper bound of Lower bound of f(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Assertion :

> Ω(O(f(n))) = O(Ω(f(n)))

To disprove, I only need to give a counter example for functions f(n),

So let f(n) = n
Assuming

> K1 <= n <= K4  ; where K1, K4, n > 0

Thus :

> O(n) = K4   ; where K3 <= K4 <= K5 for some K3, K5 > 0
>
> Ω(n) = K1    ; where K0 <= K1 <= K2 for some K1, K2 > 0

Now,

> O(K1) = K2
>
> Ω(K4) = K3

Can I now state, K2 <= K3 Hence assertion is disapproved ?? But what if the equal stands ??

Comment: Is O(Omega(f(n)) even meaningful? Isn't every function O(Omega(f(n)) for all functions f(n), since you can just pick some absurdly fast-growing function for the Omega(f(n)) term and then use that as your O bound?

Comment: What definitions are you using for O(Omega(f(n)) and Omega(O(f(n))? This isn't standard.

Comment: You might want to read up on the formal definitions of Big-O and Omega, because what you're doing there fundamentally goes against what the definitions say. You seem to be treating Big-O and Omega like number variables, when they're in fact more like infinite sets of functions.

Comment: umm, I get your reasoning. I guess in typing out the mathematical notation got mixed. 
What I meant was if f(y) is say  y=4 +(0)y and y is in the range 2 to 5, ie Omega(y) is  y = 2  +(0)y and O(y) is y=5  +(0)y . Does that make sense ? Or am I wrong fundamentally ?

Comment: @templatetypedef that is exactly my point, and a similar reasoning for Omega(O(n)) equal f(n) can be made ? That is, the lowest bound of a very slow growth function as the O(f(n)) for all functions is f(n). And hence the assertion has a chance of holding true ?

Comment: I think your error is that you're constraining the ranges on your variables. Asymptotic notation always talks about what happens in the long run as n increases, not about what happens for n in small ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is not correct because portion below;

> K1 <= n <= K4 ; where K1, K4, n > 0

You can not use numbers `K1` and `K4` for prove or disapprove these relations because in `asymptotic notations`, you should use `function`.

You can use below solution for disapprove this relation:

```
f(n) = n

h(n) = O(f(n)) => h(n) <= f(n)
```

I assume (**Counterexample**)

```
h(n) = n
```

For the right side of the relation, I assume that

```
f(n) = n

g(n) = Ω(f(n)) => f(n) <= g(n)
```

I assume (**Counterexample**)

```
g(n) = log n
```

By replacing these functions in the first relationship we have;

```
Ω(O(f(n))) = O(Ω(f(n))) =>

Ω(h(n)) = O(g(n)) =>

Ω(n) = O(log n)
```

As the same way, we can assume:

```
k(n) = Ω(n)
```

I assume (**Counterexample**)

```
k(n) = n
```

Finally we have:

```
Ω(n) = O(log n) =>

n = O(log n)
```

this result (`n = O(log n)`) is not correct and first relationship is not correct.

Comment: @SaleemAhmed Please up-vote my answer for knowing and helping other people that it helps you because some people only see the up-voted answers.